# Implementing setjmp and longjmp in C without built in functions or assembly (getting incorrect return values)

Tags: c, pointers, stack, setjmp

I'm trying to test 2 of my functions that sort of mimic setjmp and longjmp for a homework - which is pretty difficult since we're not allowed to use built in functions or assembly asm() to implement the longjmp and setjmp functions. (Yes, [that's really the assignment](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxnhsPyPkMIsVXNTZnFyek1hdzg).)

**Problem**: I keep getting wrong return values. So, in short, when main() calls foo() and foo() calls bar(), and bar() calls longjump(), then bar() should not return to foo() but instead setjmp() should return to main with return value of 1 which should print "error" (see main() below).

Instead, my output comes out as:

```
start foo
start bar
segmentation fault
```

The segmentation fault, i tried fixing by initializing the pointer *p with malloc, but that didn't seem to do anything. Although, would the segmentation fault, be the reason why im not getting the correct return values?

**code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int setjmp(int v);
int longjmp(int v);
int foo(void);
int bar(void);
int *add;


int main(void) {

    int r;

    r = setjmp(r);
    if(r == 0) {
        foo();
        return(0);
    } else {
        printf("error\n");
        return(2);
    }

}

int _main(void) {
    return(0);
}

int setjmp(int v)
{
    add = &v;
    return(0);
}

int longjmp(int v)
{
    int *p;
    p = &v;
    *(p - 1) = *add;
    return(1);
}

int foo(void) {
    printf("start foo\n");
    bar();
    return(0);
}

int bar(void) {
    int d;
    printf("start bar\n");
    longjmp(d);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: There's no way to implement `setjmp` and `longjmp` yourself in standard C. If this is really your assignment, you're going to be diving deep into undefined behavior land.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to write your own function with the same name as a standard library function (even if you didn't include the header) . You shoudl call your functions something else

Comment: Your `setjmp(r)` reads an uninitialized variable, which is also undefined behaviour in this context  , not clear what you are trying to do there

Comment: @M.M he tries to somehow save an address of a function parameter on stack to re-set $rsp later on based on the saved value *cries hysterically in x64*

Comment: @user2357112 I'm fully aware of this and think the homework given to us is really a terrible and dangerous way to teach programming, however, I'm still required to do the assignment if I want to get a decent grade for the class.

Comment: @iehrlich maybe passing `&r` would match the intent better then

Comment: @M.M it's still a road to nowhere, since the offset between &r and $rsp in the caller is unknown. At this point, I just wanted to clarify this moment for you :)

Comment: @adventuredoge: Show us your actual assignment. You've probably misunderstood what it's about.

Comment: @adventuredoge to my mind, it's actually a perfect and safest way to teach programming, since you can't just copy this homework mindlessly. That's why you are here - and you are learning something. Your teacher is awesome.

Comment: @user2357112 here's the instructions to my assignment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxnhsPyPkMIsVXNTZnFyek1hdzg

Comment: Oh geeze, it really is just telling you to implement setjmp and longjmp. It's in the specific context of a MIPS simulator and a specific compiler, though. You're going to need to rely on the details of those things.

Comment: Seriously, though, no asm or builtins? How do they expect you to manipulate registers? Hopefully they provide something that isn't apparent from just this assignment sheet. The use of the uninitialized, apparently-useless `r` argument is straight from the assignment, too, and this thing has pre-standard, K&R-style function definitions. I sympathize with you, but I don't know if there's much we can do to help.

Comment: At this point, I simply wrote a letter to the guy. Unfortunately, It was only after I sent the mail I realized there are actually number of them, but I *hope* I was lucky enough to pick the right target ^_^

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The overview (first full paragraph) makes it clear that isn't the intent: "In this project, you will write the code of two C functions called setjmp() and longjmp()…"

Comment: Right you are, the non-highlighted part makes that clear. This will be fun...

Comment: @adventuredoge at this point I would consider *finding another school*.

Answer (score 5):

Implementing `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` requires access to the stack pointer. Unfortunately, the assignment you're working from has *explicitly* banned you from using every sensible method to do this (i.e, using assembly, or using compiler builtins to access the stack pointer).

What's worse is, they've mangled the definition of `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` in their sample code. The argument needs to be a type that resolves to an array (e.g, `typedef int jmp_buf[1]`), not an `int`…

Anyways. You need some way to reliably find the old stack pointer from a stack frame in C. Probably the best way of doing this will be to define an array on the stack, then look "behind" it…

```
void get_sp(void) {
    int x[1];
    sp = x[-1]; // or -2 or -3, etc…
```

The exact offset will depend on what compiler you're using, as well as possibly on what arguments your function takes and what other local variables the function has. **You will need to experiment a bit to get this right.** Run your application in the simulator, and/or look at the generated assembly, to make sure you're picking up the right value.

The same trick will probably work to set the stack pointer when "returning" from `longjmp()`. However, certain compiler optimizations may make this difficult, especially on architectures with a link register -- such as MIPS. Make sure compiler optimizations are disabled. If all else fails, you may need to call a dummy function in `longjmp()` to force the compiler to save the link register on the stack, rather than leaving it in a register (where it can't be overwritten).

Comment: Thank you! I'll experiment with this.

Comment: The stack grows downward, so you need positive offsets from locals to access the `lr`, not negative offsets.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to need to deal with the link register, the stack pointer, and the frame pointer (you would normally also have to save and restore all of the save registers, but I don't think we need to in order to make this example work).

Take a look at the `arg3caller` function [here](http://winfred-lu.blogspot.com/2009/12/mips-calling-convention-with-gcc.html).  Upon entry, it stores the link register and the frame pointer on the stack, and sets the frame pointer to point to the new stack frame.  It then calls `args3`, sets the return value, and, most importantly, copies the frame pointer back into the stack pointer.  It then pops the link register and the original frame pointer from where the stack pointer is now located, and jumps to the link register.  If you look at `args3`, it saves the frame pointer into the stack and then restores it from the stack.

So, `arg3caller` can be `longjmp`, but if you want it to return with a different stack pointer than it entered with, you are going to have to change the frame pointer, because the frame pointer gets copied into the stack pointer at then end.  The frame pointer can be modified by having `args3` (a dummy function called by `longjmp`) modify the copy of the frame pointer that it saved in the stack.

You will need to make `setjmp` also call a dummy function in order to get the link register and frame pointer stored on the stack in the same way.  You can then copy the link register and frame pointer out of `setjmp`'s stack frame into globals (normally, `setjmp` would copy stuff into the provided `jmpbuf`, but here, the arguments to `setjmp` and `longjmp` are useless, so you have to use globals), as well as the address of the frame.  Then, `longjmp` must copy the saved link register and frame pointer back into the same address, and have the dummy leaf function change the saved frame pointer to that same address.  Thus, the dummy leaf function will copy that address into the frame pointer and return to `longjmp`, which will copy it into the stack pointer.  It will then restore the frame pointer and the link register from that stack frame (that you populated), thus returning with everything in the state that it was when `setjmp` originally returned (except the return value will be different).

Note that you can access these fields by using the negative indexing of a local array trick described by @duskwuff.  You should initially compile with the `-S` flag so that you can see what asm gcc is generating so that you can see where the important registers are being saved in the stack (and how your code might perturb all of that).

**Edit:**

I don't have immediate access to a MIPS gcc, but I found [this](https://godbolt.org), and put it in MIPS gcc 5.4 mode.  Playing around, I found that non-leaf functions store `lr` and `fp` immediately below where the argument would be placed on the stack (the argument is actually passed in `a0`, but gcc leaves room for it on the stack in case the callee needs to store it).  By having `setjmp` call a leaf function, we can ensure that `setjmp` is a non-leaf so that its `lr` is saved on the stack.  We can then save the address of the arg, and the `lr` and `fp` that are stored immediately below it (using negative indexing), and return 0.  Then, in `longjmp`, we can call a leaf function to ensure the `lr` is saved on the stack, but also have the leaf change *its* stacked `fp` to the saved `sp`.  Upon return to `longjmp`, the `fp` will be pointing at the original frame, which we can re-populate with the saved `lr` and `fp`.  Returning from `longjmp` will copy the `fp` back into the `sp` and restore the `lr` and `fp` from our re-populated frame, making it appear that we are returning from `setjmp`.  This time however, we return 1 so the caller can differentiate the true return from `setjmp` to the fake one engineered by `longjmp`.

Note that I have only eyeballed this code, and have not actually executed it!!  Also, it must be compiled with optimization disabled (`-O0`).  If you enable any kind of optimization, the compiler inlines the leaf functions and turns both `setjmp` and `longjmp` into empty functions.  You should see what your compiler does with this to understand how the stack frames are constructed.  Again, we're well and truly in the land of undefined behavior, and even changes in gcc version could upset everything.  You should also single step the program (using `gdb` or `spim`) to make sure you understand what's going on.

```
struct jmpbuf {
    int lr;
    int fp;
    int *sp;
};

static struct jmpbuf ctx;

static void setjmp_leaf(void) { }

int setjmp(int arg)
{
    // call the leaf so that our lr is saved
    setjmp_leaf();

    // the address of our arg should be immediately
    // above the lr and fp
    ctx.sp = &arg;

    // lr is immediately below arg
    ctx.lr = (&arg)[-1];

    // fp is below that
    ctx.fp = (&arg)[-2];

    return 0;
}

static void longjmp_leaf(int arg)
{
    // overwrite the caller's frame pointer
    (&arg)[-1] = (int)ctx.sp;
}

int longjmp(int arg)
{
    // call the leaf so that our lr is saved
    // but also to change our fp to the save sp
    longjmp_leaf(arg);

    // repopulate the new stack frame with the saved
    // lr and fp.  &arg is calculated relative to fp,
    // which was modified by longjmp_leaf.  &arg isn't
    // where it used to be!
    (&arg)[-1] = ctx.lr;
    (&arg)[-2] = ctx.fp;

    // this should restore the saved fp and lr
    // from the new frame, so it looks like we're
    // returning from setjmp
    return 1;
}
```

Good luck!